# How can i achive file upload dialog box in android through java or xml layout

Tags: android, file-upload

Im new to android, developing a social networking application which requires user to upload images, but i dont know how to achive the file upload dialog box. How can we achive it,using java file or xml layout file?

Answer (score 1):

The uploading file can be viewed as the set of actions

1. Browse for file
2. Select file for upload
3. Upload file

So you need to combine these 3 steps to upload file.

If you are curious about actual upload - here is the [link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3PAtcwWWs3oJ:www.anddev.org/upload_files_to_web_server-t443-s30.html+android+file+upload&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk) on example

Comment: im basically interested in selecting a image file using file upload dialog